# How to calculate country code from IPv6

Tags: java, geolocation, ip, country-codes

is there any chance to calculate country code from IPv6 ? In case of IPv4 I did it by multiplying particular ip parts by 256. Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: There are geolocation databases where you can look up the country code.

One of those that I know of that support IPv6 is MaxMind https://support.maxmind.com/ipv6-data-faq/ or http://ipinfo.io/